# How to create a admin login session in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter

```
if($data)
{
  $pass = $data['password'];
  $authenticatePassword = password_verify($password, $pass);
  if($authenticatePassword)
  {
    $ses_data = [
      'id' => $data['id'],
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'isLoggedIn' => TRUE
    ];
    $session->set($ses_data);
    return redirect()->to('/profile');
```

I want to make it so the admin can log in and direct it to his page.

Comment: Please see [ask], which instructs to describe your problem _before_ showing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this in your admin controller

```
function index()
{
    if($data)
    {
        $username= $this->input->post('username');
        $password= $this->input->post('password');
        $row= $this->admins->adminLogin($username, $password);
        if(count($row)==1)
        {
            foreach($row as $val)
                {
                    $data= array('USERID' =>$val->id,
                            'USERNAME' => $val->username,
                            'logged_in' => true,
                            'id' => $val->id,
                            );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                }
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message','<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Username and Password.</div>');
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/index');
}
```